# ui-element-id in angular apps css styling

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, uielement

I have a question about ui-element-id's styling. What is the difference between normal html/css id/#, and how you can style ui-element-id's with css (if it's possible)?

My example:
HTML/

This Alert is dangerous

CSS(Sass)/
/deep/ #dangerAlert
    background: green
    color: green
    span.text-danger
        color: blue

But /deep/ selector isn't working.

Thanks!

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to achieve or explain your question little bit more?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to better help you, would you please update your question to contain all relevant code in a [minimal, complete & verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Additionally, providing screenshots of the problem and details of what you’ve tried, make it much more likely that you’ll get a useful answer. 

For further information, please refer to the help article regarding **[how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.